# Warning messages in occupancy modelling (unmarked)

Tags: r, modeling, model-selection, estimators, ecology

I have an issue with occupancy modelling and I have some warning messages that I don’t understand. I hope you can explain to me what they mean and how I can resolve them.
I am building single-species, single-season occupancy models with the “unmarked” package in R.

var.site are my covariables, which have been z-scored.
speciesshort is my occupancy data for the species of interest (divided in 10 columns which represent separate surveys)

I built the following model:

```
species_occu<-unmarkedFrameOccu(y=speciesshort,siteCovs=var.site)
```

First, I tried to find the best model for detection, while keeping the occupancy constant (~1). Like this:

```
m0<-occu(~1~1,species_occu)
d1<-occu(~DET1~1, species_occu)
d2<-occu(~DET2~1, species_occu)
d3<-occu(~DET3~1, species_occu)
d4<-occu(~DET4~1, species_occu)
d5<-occu(~DET5~1, species_occu)
d6<-occu(~DET6~1, species_occu)
```

This went fine and I selected the best detection model, in this case a model that had the variable NO_HUMAN_DAY. I then proceeded to look at the influence of different land types on the occupancy. Like this:

```
m0<-occu(~NO_HUMAN_DAY~1, species_occu)
o1<-occu(~NO_HUMAN_DAY~Primary_Forest, species_occu)
o3<-occu(~NO_HUMAN_DAY~Coffee, species_occu)
o4<-occu(~NO_HUMAN_DAY~Grassland, species_occu)
o5<-occu(~NO_HUMAN_DAY~Urban, species_occu)
o6<-occu(~NO_HUMAN_DAY~Palm, species_occu)
```

When I look at the summaries of some of my models (just by calling the model), I sometimes see very high parameter estimates, and occasionally I get the following warning message:

> Warning message: In new("standardGeneric", .Data = function (object) 
>   :   Model did not converge. Try providing starting values or
>   increasing maxit control argment.

An example is this model:

```
Occupancy:
            Estimate    SE      z P(>|z|)
(Intercept)     87.1 107.4  0.812   0.417
Grassland      -37.3  46.1 -0.810   0.418

Detection:
             Estimate    SE     z  P(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -1.525 0.154 -9.89 4.50e-23
NO_HUMAN_DAY   -0.515 0.313 -1.65 9.96e-02

AIC: 325.9645 
Warning message:
In new("standardGeneric", .Data = function (object)  :
  Model did not converge. Try providing starting values or increasing maxit control argment.
```

What do these high estimates and error messages mean? Can I still use these models or are they worthless? Is there a way to solve them or is there something wrong with my covariables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In essence, a model that doesn't converge is not publishable and should not be used. I'd assert that the only exceptions are where you are an expert and have a good specific reason for acting otherwise, and even then the other experts will probably disagree. But it is very hard to say what is behind the lack of convergence without knowing more (than zero) about your data. Perhaps you don't have the patterns the model expects. Perhaps your data is awkward in some sense. We can't say.

Comment: A specific problem here with your question is that you're relying on the title and the tag `modeling` to attract attention. I know a very little about ecological data but nothing about occupancy modeling. More positively, there are some very strong statistically-minded ecologists here and you need to attract their attention, perhaps by looking for another tag.

Comment: I am leaning towards reading this as a statistical issue rather than something specific about R.